# Accesing github secrets on GitHub Actions for a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a react app that is running in a docker container. I would like to access the value of a variable on the `.env` located in the droplet where the react app docker container is deployed to.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` of the react app

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
module.exports = {

    plugins: [
        new Dotenv()
    ],

};
```

In my `image.jss` of the react app

```
const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL
console.log(API_URL)
# return nothing on the droplet.
```

A small part of the Github actions

```
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build 
    runs-on: ubuntu
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Add environment variables to .env
        run: |
          echo REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL}} >> .env
```

Within the docker container, I am able to

```
echo $REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL # returns variable
```

In the `.env` on the `droplet`, a file does exist there called `.env` with the `REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL`.

The react is running in a docker container app. How can I make the react app access the value of `REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL` in the `.env`?.

Locally, I am able to access the `.env` and get the value of `REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create `.env` file  with your vars before build:

```
- name: Create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL}} >> .env
          cat .env
```

Alternatively using [Create Envfile Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-env-file)